# How can I run a URL directly from VBA for sending SMS messages via the web without opening IE?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a website API to send messages from Access 2010 VBA. When I press the command button, Internet Explorer opens and the message is sent.

However, for each message a separate tab opens and takes a while to send. My requirement is to send the message without opening Internet Explorer, if possible. Here's my code:

```
Function Send_Message()

    MemApiKey = "USL"
    MemMobNo = "03071913090"
    MemMasking = "APIKEY"
    MemBody = "This is Test Message"
    MemApiKey = "5b873e271974fdf9e3edd85c3dabd22f"

    With CodeContextObject
        Dim WebLink As String
        WebLink = "http://csms.voguetech.com.pk/api_sms/api.php?key=" & MemApiKey & "&receiver=" & MemMobNo & "&sender=" & MemMasking & "&msgdata=Paksuite1"

        Application.FollowHyperlink WebLink, , True

        WebLink = "http://csms.voguetech.com.pk/api_sms/api.php?key=" & MemApiKey & "&receiver=" & MemMobNo & "&sender=" & MemMasking & "&msgdata=Global Care2"

        Application.FollowHyperlink WebLink, , True

    End With
End Function
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].What is`CodeContextObject`? Never used or declared! Use`Option Explicit`on top of every module to avoid that.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher CodeContextObject is a Microsoft Access application object that is available in all contexts.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to the following based on feedback in the comments (removing the `TRUE` parameter):

```
strURL = "http://csms.voguetech.com.pk/api_sms/api.php?key=" & MemApiKey & "&receiver=" & MemMobNo & "&sender=" & MemMasking & "&msgdata=SSS Care Solutions"
Application.FollowHyperlink strURL, , False, False, , msoMethodPost
```

It is now working well.

Comment: Even you improved by avoiding new tabs, you use unnecessary parameters in FollowHyperlink (skip all but strUrl!) and using a Browser for  a HttpGetRequest is waste of resources. There are specialized classes like`WinHttpRequest.5.1`or `XmlServerHttp`that use less resources.